# JBoss 5.0.1 clustering

Tags: jboss

Hi I am new in JBoss,
I just wana know Steps for Clustering in JBoss 5.0.1
Steps means
1)how to create new node for clustering.
2)which .XML file's need to be changed
3) how to run different nodes
4) how to stop diff nodes
5) how do i know bothe node's are working.

Thanks if any one just help me out.

Answer (score 3):

I found the [documentation](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS5ClusteringGuide) very useful.